# Android make text bold when touched or pressed

Tags: android

There are similar questions here but without answer.
I have a listview with textviews and I want those textviews make bold when they pressed.
I overrided onTouchEvent like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
                setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.listview_textcolor_pressed));
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL);
                setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.listview_textcolor));
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

It's working, but as you see I'm returning true and system does not care about this event anymore and thats why other selectors such as background color of the row is not applying.

Maybe there is other solution on how to bold text when pressed and make normal when not pressed?

style="@style/myStyle" in xml selector is not working. Please do not propose it :)

Comment: Err, why don't you return false then?

Comment: Returning false would allow the event to propagate further, if that's what you want; it's not too clear from your question.

Comment: Returning false tell the system that this event is not more maintained. This means that if I return false I'll not get Motionevent.ACTION_UP event. And that's why I'll be unavailable to setTypeFace to normal (not bold)

Comment: Return "super.onTouchEvent".

Comment: Thrash, super also return false...

Comment: On ACTION_DOWN, set the clicked View to bold and any other views to normal?  You might consider storing a boolean (bold or not) in the tag for quick and easy enumeration.